# pythonのgroupbyから取得できる値

Tags: python, pandas

いつもお世話になっております。
タイポからたまたま正解に辿り着けたのですが、ロジックがわからず、ご指導をお願いします。

■出力データ

```
#       date       area    resident valueA   valueB  SD  KM
48597  2019-01-26  tokyo   man      75000    6.96     1.1  1.1
48598  2019-01-26  tokyo   woman    75000    6.96     1.1  1.1
```

以下のコードの出力をすると、上記のような結果が得られます。この場合、goupbyで取得した値が、b.max()[0]は、dateを日付として取得することがわかるのですが、valueAを取得するための値が、b.mean()[1]ではなく、b.mean()[0]となります。この理由はなんでしょうか？

b.max()[0] ---> date
b.mean()[1] ---> valueA　【不正解】
b.mean()[0] ---> valueA　【正解】

■ソースコード

```
df = pd.read_csv(f,header=None, usecols=[0,1, 2,10,11,13,14], names=['date','area','resident','valueA','valueB','SD','KM'], dtype={'date':'str','area':'str','resident':'str','valueA':'int','valueB':'float','SD':'float','KM':'float'})

for a,b in df.groupby(['area', 'resident'], as_index=False):
print(b.max()[0])  #date

print(a[0])
print(a[1])

print(b.count()[1]) #count
print(int(b.mean()[0])) #valueA
print(round(b.mean()[1],2)) #valueB
print(round(b.mean()[2],2)) #SD
print(round(b.mean()[3],2)) #KM
```

■参照csvデータ (以下のようなデータが大量に並ぶ)

```
2019-01-26,tokyo,man,nameA,areaA,detailA,4,13,199000,15000,214000,16.77,A,1.0,1.0
2019-01-26,tokyo,man,nameA,areaA,detailB,4,13,208000,15000,223000,16.87,B,1.0,1.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

とりあえず、下記を見てください
それぞれ、**dateteime型**,**object型**(str型),**int型**,**float型**のデータを持つ列 DataFrameを作成して、`dataframe.max(`) および `dataframe.mean()` を行った結果となります。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N=5
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'datetime型': pd.date_range('2019/1/1', periods=N, freq='1d'),
     'str型': list('ABCDE'),
     'int型': np.random.randint(0,10000,N),
     'float型': np.random.uniform(0.,10.,N)
    }
)
print(df)
#   datetime型    float型  int型 str型
#0 2019-01-01  5.746031  8496    A
#1 2019-01-02  6.586894  8338    B
#2 2019-01-03  0.605272  2340    C
#3 2019-01-04  1.547762   193    D
#4 2019-01-05  3.148205  3055    E


## 各列の型を確認
print(df.dtypes)
#datetime型    datetime64[ns]
#float型              float64
#int型                  int32
#str型                 object
#dtype: object

## 各列の最大を表示
print(df.max())
#datetime型    2019-01-05 00:00:00
#float型                   6.58689
#int型                        8496
#str型                           E
#dtype: object

## 列毎の平均を表示【 datetime型とstr型の列が無い！！！】
print(df.mean())
#float型       3.526833
#int型      4484.400000
#dtype: float64
```

この結果からお解かりの通り**datetime型**や**object型**の列は、`dataframe.max()` を使って最大値を得ることが出来るのですが、`dataframe.mean()` による平均値の取得は得ることが出来ない（計算できないので省かれる）ということになります。

で、質問のコードの場合ですが、`b.mean()` を行った際に同じ理由により **'date'** 列の結果が得られないため、Index値がその分一つズレます。その結果 **valueA**の平均値は

```
b.mean()[0]
```

で得られるということになります。

個人的には、このような場合は **column index** を使用するのではなく **column name**を利用して

```
b.mean()['valueA']
```

とするほうが良いかと思います。